# Keep Google OAuth User Logged-in on Refresh

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, refresh-token

I'm using the Google Calendar API and can't figure out how to keep the user logged in when they refresh the page. I can't find anything online about this. If anyone could help, it'd be greatly appreciated! This is my current code to login the user:

```
function handleAuthClick() {
    tokenClient.callback = async (resp) => {
        if (resp.error !== undefined) {
            throw (resp);
        }
        await listUpcomingEvents();
    };

    if (gapi.client.getToken() === null) {
        tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: 'consent'});
    } else {
        tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: ''});
    }
}
```

My `body` element automatically runs this on load. I'm using this guide: https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/js.

Comment: have you tried storing the access token and using the stored access token - you added the `cookies` tag to your question, but there is zero evidence you are actually using cookies, yet cookies is one way to store the token - have you tried?

Comment: @Bravo I did try to use local storage and ended up with this code: https://pastebin.com/6s6PQg81. However, when I refreshed the page, it would log me out and not allow me to log back in.

Comment: "this code" is not the code in the question - so - `if(localStorage.getItem("authToken") === "null") {` will ALWAYS be false unless you, for some bizarre reason you do `localStorage.setItem("authToken", "null")` - but ... why would you store such a string?

Comment: @Bravo, that's my mistake. It was meant to be just the boolean null, with no quotations (which didn't work either).

Comment: the boolean null??? anyway - you have one tiny bit of code here, another on a pastebin ... neither are enough to help - for example ... there's no else on the pastebin, so you don't even bother to show what you do when there IS a token stored in loacStorage - you probably doing it wrong

Comment: Anyway, as far as the code in the question goes, you'll need to store the token somewhere if you want to use it after a page reload ... a cookie or localStorage